# Reading columns of numbers in C

Tags: c

EDIT: I'm sorry for the dumb quesion I was lacking sleep and could'nt see things right.
Thankyou everyone

I dont know why or how but i doublechecked the code and it crashes, this is an example of the code that generates de crash and i dont get it.
I've been through other questions regarding the matter but trying the solutions people give still isn't effective. The kind of txt I'm trying to read is like this:

> 0 0 -1.000047e+000
>
> 0 1 -1.000047e+000
>
> 0 2 -1.000047e+000
>
> 0 3 -1.000047e+000
>
> 0 4 -1.000047e+000
>
> 0 5 -1.000047e+000
>
> 1 0 -1.000047e+000
>
> 1 1 -1.000047e+000

And and extract of my code which fails, I dont have any kind of while/if/anything regards of arriving at end of the file or anything similar because I always know how many values has the .txt that I have to read (it's created by a previous program which I wrote, by the way I'm rather new with C):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

const int   Nx=88;          // lattice size X
const int   Ny=44;          // lattice size Y

double *phi;



int main() {
int i, j, ki, kj, index;
FILE * conf;
FILE * fp;

fp = fopen ("test.txt","w+");
conf = fopen ("InitConditions.txt", "r");  /* open the file for reading */

ki=0;
kj=0;

for (i=0; i<Nx; i++){   

    for (j=0; j<Ny; j++){
        
        index=get_index(i,j);
        printf("%i",index);
        fscanf(conf,"%i %i %lf", &ki, &kj,  &phi[index]);
    }

}    

return (0);
}

int get_index(int i, int j){

int index;

index=i*Ny+j;

return index;
}
```

The error is something like

> Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 7 second(s))

Which I dont understand

Comment: Where do you initialize the variable `phi` to point to a valid memory address (of a block of an appropriate size which has been properly allocated in memory prior to any read or write access via `phi`)???

Comment: double *phi is not initialized. When you try to store something in an uninitialized pointer the results are undefined.

Comment: Does your input file really have blank lines in between the rows of numbers? Have you though about checking the return of `fscanf` to *validate* the conversions?

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf()`, will crash because you are using `&phi[index]` there, but `phi` is not pointing to memory that you have allocated.

You need to allocate the needed memory first.

```
if((phi = malloc(Nx * Ny * sizeof(double))) == NULL) { /* Allocate memory */
    /* Error handling code */       
    exit(1);
}
/* ... */
/* ... */

for (i=0; i<Nx; i++) {   
    for (j=0; j<Ny; j++) {
        index=get_index(i,j);
        printf("%i",index);
        if (fscanf(conf,"%i %i %lf", &ki, &kj,  &phi[index]) != 3) {
            /* Code to handle fscanf failure */
        }
    }
}

/* .... */
/* .... */
free(phi);  /* Free the allocated memory when it is not needed anymore */
```

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Your primary issue was attempting to use an uninitialized pointer `phi` that points nowhere. Since you know the maximum number of elements, and they are a reasonable number, simply declare `phi[Nx * Ny]` and use automatic storage.

However, most of your additional errors flow from a failure to validate any of your file opens, or reads from the file. If your file does have the blank lines you show, then you are ill advised to use `fscanf` to attempt to read/parse the file into your actual values. You can use temporary values, but you are far better served using `fgets` to read each line into a buffer, and then parse the buffer to extract the data you need. This separates the read from the testing of the number of conversions allowing greater flexibility in testing the line and parsing the values.

Putting those pieces together and commenting out the unused code and header files, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { Ny = 44, Nx = 88, MAXC = 128 };  /* constants */

int get_index (int i, int j);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i, j, ki, kj, index;
    double phi[Nx * Ny] = { 0.0 };
    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *conf/*, *fp*/;

    /*
    if (!(fp = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "test.txt", "w+"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: output file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    } */
    if (!(conf = fopen (argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "InitConditions.txt", "r"))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: input file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    i = j = ki = kj = index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < Nx; i++) {                  /* for each i */
        for (j = 0; j < Ny; j++) {              /* for each j */
            index = get_index (i, j);           /* compute index */
            while (fgets (buf, MAXC, conf)) {   /* read line into buf */
                int tmpki, tmpkj;               /* tmp vars to hold values */
                double tmpphi;
                /* if line holds 3 values, then assign to array */
                if (sscanf (buf, "%d %d %lf", &tmpki, &tmpkj, &tmpphi) == 3) {
                    ki = tmpki;
                    kj = tmpkj;
                    phi[index] = tmpphi;
                    /* test print */
                    printf (" phi[%4d] : %.6le\n", index, phi[index]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_index (int i, int j)
{
    int index;

    index = i * Ny + j;

    return index;
}
```

(**note:** since you are looping `i` and `j`, you must force the read of `1` set of values per iteration. Using `while (fgets...` and breaking the read on successful parse of values allows you to accomplish this.)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rdivals stuff dat/ivals.txt
 phi[   0] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   1] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   2] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   3] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   4] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   5] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   6] : -1.000047e+00
 phi[   7] : -1.000047e+00
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions. If I missed the logic in your question, just let me know and I'm happy to work with you further.